# ReactJs & NodeJs Deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to Reactjs. I have a Linux server where my reactjs is running in 3000 port and nodejs is running in 3001 port.

Now how I could deploy my reactjs and nodejs in the production on the same server? Also, I found that in production reactjs doesn't allow localhost, so how could I fetch the API which is running in port 3001.

Thanks

Comment: Exchange the `url` argument with the actual URL where your server is deployed, instead of `fetch('http://localhost:3001')` change it to `fetch('https://my.server.com')`

Comment: that was not my question

Comment: "*how could I fetch the API which is running in port 3001*" add `:3001` to the end of the URL.

Comment: "*how I could deploy my reactjs and nodejs in the production on the same server*" many google results shows the old heroku ways, nowadays maybe [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploying-your-reactjs-nodejs-server-rendercom-serena-dean) would help you deploy on alternatives like: Render.com